# How to use unicode with enlive for web-scraping

Tags: clojure, enlive

I'm trying to scrape a few sites that require unicode support. For example, I'm trying to get the title of this book, but it returns jumbled characters:

```
(-> "http://www.brill.nl/publications/evliya-celebis-book-travels" 
      java.net.URL. enlive/html-resource
 (enlive/select [:h1#page-title]) first :content)
```

And trying to scrape an Arabic site returns with ?????? all over the place.

```
(enlive/html-resource (java.net.URL. "http://www.aljazeera.net/portal"))
```

I'm not sure how I'm supposed to activate unicode support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enlive does have unicode support because it uses Java strings. I ran your first example on my computer and got this result:

```
(Evliyā Çelebi's Book of Travels)
```

Perhaps the font that you are using doesn't have glyphs for the pointcodes that you are trying to show?

Comment: I'm on a Mac using Deja Vu Sans Mono on the standard terminal with unicode Utf-8. I even tried it with iterm2. All it returns with is  ("Evliy? ?elebi's Book of Travels"). **BUT** if i spit it out to a file like "titles.txt" then it displays the title correctly. **Yet** if i copy and past the title back in to the repl and run (.codePointAt "Evliyā Çelebi's Book of Travels" 5) I get 402, but if run the same code on the string returned by enlive i get 257. (char 402) and (char 257) both return ?. What are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Christophe Grand, the author of enlive, was kind of enough to [reply on the Enlive email group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/enlive-clj/kl-xVdGRkGQ). His suggestion was quite informative. I have copied the email below:

> Hello,
>
> Enlive is not (and does not include) a full-featured HTTP agent.
> When you pass a java.net.URL to a html-resource it call .getContent on it, get an InputStream an then assume UTF-8.
> However if you know the actual encoding you can do :

```
(-> "http://www.brill.nl/publications/evliya-celebis-book-travels" java.net.URL.
  .getContent (java.io.InputStreamReader. "ENCODING GOES HERE")
enlive/html-resource
 (en/select [:h1#page-title]) first :content)
```

> Or use an agent library which will detect the correct encoding and pass the resulting Reader to html-resource.
>
> hth,
>
> Christophe